# Unable to run model.predict() with image shape same as that which the model was trained on

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, opencv, deep-learning

I am trying to run inference on a ResNet model that I had designed and trained on google Colab, the link to the notebook can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oahmAcbdXZS0wB0bV6MGXCzGLY97YY68?usp=sharing). The dimension of the images that the model is trained on is (32, 32, 3). After training, I saved the model in the `SavedModel` format so that I could run Inference on my machine. The code I used is

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2 as cv
from resize import resize_to_fit

image = cv.imread('extracted_letter_images/001.png')
image_resized = resize_to_fit(image, 32, 32)
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('Model/CAPTCHA-Model')
model.predict(image_resized)
```

The `resize_to_fit` method resizes the image to 32x32px. The shape of the returned image is also (32, 32, 3). When the `model.predict()` function is called, the following error message is shown

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (32, 32, 3)
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling `Tensorflow` as well as `tf-nightly` several times to no avail. I have even tried expanding the dimension of the image with this

```
image_resized = np.expand_dims(image_resized, axis=0)
```

This results in the image having dimensions (1, 32, 32, 3). When the above change is made the following error message is shown

```
2021-04-07 19:49:11.821261: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:180] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
```

What I'm confused about is that the dimensions of the resized image and the dimensions of the image used the train the model is the same but `model.predict()` does not seem to work.

Comment: '2021-04-07 19:49:11.821261: I ...' is not error, it's just informational message. You expanding the dimension did the trick as tensorflow predict expects vector input.

Answer (score 0):

In your ImageDataGenerators you used the preprocessing function tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale. This converted the images to 32 X 32 X 1. So you must do the same transformation on the images you wish to predict. You also rescaled the images to be in the range 0 to 1 so you must also rescale the images you wish to predict. The code image_resized = np.expand_dims(image_resized, axis=0) is correct. Not sure if his will be an issue but be aware that cv2 reads in images as BGR not RGB so before you apply tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale first convert the image to RGB with image= cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB).

Comment: I've tried the suggestions that you gave and the error message now stands as `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 32, 32)` I don't think the way openCV reads images matters in this case as all images are black and white.